# How to hash a string based on character in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I Have a string input INDIA. I want to create a hash which contains different characters in the input and their frequency. How to implement it ?

Comment: How about using an `NSCountedSet` ?

Comment: Can you guide me how use them with some code.

Comment: @AshutoshPandey consider giving feedback on the answer below: did this solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

`NSOrderedSet` could be fit for the purpose, but the issue (in this use case) is that it's an unordered collection (just a bag), so to maintain the order of the characters in the input string in the produced hash, some fixes would need to be added that would reduce the useability of the `NSOrderedSet` approach in the first place.

Another alternative is to implement your own "ordered bag", which counts the frequency of each character in the input string, and produces an array of 2-element tuples (ordered collection), where the first tuple members annotates the character and the second the count of that character in the input string.

```
extension Collection where Iterator.Element: Hashable {
    var frequencies: [(Iterator.Element, Int)] {
        var seen: [Iterator.Element: Int] = [:]
        var frequencies: [(Iterator.Element, Int)] = []
        for element in self {
            if let idx = seen[element] {
                frequencies[idx].1 += 1
            }
            else {
                seen[element] = frequencies.count
                frequencies.append((element, 1))
            }
        }
        return frequencies
    }
}
```

With this you can readily compute your custom hash:

```
extension String {
    // lowercase the String as not to differ between upper
    // and lower case characters when computing the hash
    var customHash: String {
        return lowercased().characters.frequencies
            .reduce("") { $0 + String($1.0) + String($1.1) }
    }
}

let str1 = "INDIA"
let str2 = "United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland"

print(str1.customHash) // i2n1d1a1
print(str2.customHash) // u1n7i5t4e4d4 7k1g2o3m1f1r5a4b1h1l1
```