# getting unique items in an array

Tags: ios, swift

I have an array which has repeated items, i want to get unique items only so i did this:

```
    let decoded  = userDefaults.object(forKey: "shifts") as! Data
    myShifts = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: decoded) as! [Shift]
    filtered_shifts = myShifts.filter{$0.regionName == region && $0.cityName == city && $0.idService == idservice && $0.quantityStaff != 0}
    for shift in filtered_shifts {
        let decoded4  = userDefaults.object(forKey: "nationalities") as! Data
        let decodedNationalities = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: decoded4) as! [Nationality]
        for nationality in decodedNationalities {
            if nationality.id == shift.idNationality{
                nationalitiesid.append(nationality.id)
                nationalities.append(nationality.name)
            }
        }
    }
    uniqueNationality = Array(Set(nationalities))
    uniqueNationalityid = Array(Set(nationalitiesid))
```

which is getting me a new array with unique items as i need...

the problem is that the order is diferent when i want the same order ... for exampple:

> nationalitiesid = [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4]
>
> nationalities = ["Indian", "Indian", "Indian", "Indian", "Indian", "Indian", "Indian", "Indian", "Philippines", "Philippines", "Philippines", "Philippines"]

the unique array is:

> uniqueNationality = ["Indian", "Philippines"]
>
> uniqueNationalityid = [4, 3]

and this is wrong since Indian id is 3 and Philippines id is 4!

it should be:

> uniqueNationalityid = [3, 4]

How to solve this?

Comment: `Set`s are unordered. Why do you want to keep them separated while they are meant to be synchronized?

Comment: @Larme then how to do it?

Comment: @PPL the link is doing what am doing ...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41272542/find-unique-values-in-a-swift-array/43753028#43753028

Comment: @VishalVaghasiya am already getting the unique array correctly .. my problem is the order of it's elements

Comment: @Scriptable am already getting the unique array correctly .. my problem is the order of it's elements

Comment: Can i ask why you have seperate arrays with id and name of nationality? these could easily be grouped into their own type which would get rid of your issue?

Comment: @Scriptable because am displaying the names for user .. and saving the id to be sent to the server.. please tell me if there's a better way to do this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
let uniqueList = nationalities.reduce([], {
    $0.contains($1) ? $0 : $0 + [$1]
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much! i think you are the only one who understood what was my problem is! THANKS ALOT!

Answer (score 0):

This does not directly answer the question. This is an alternative solution. Using a model to group the related information rather keeping two separate arrays in sync.

For more information on Structs and Classes check the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html)

```
struct Nationality {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
}

let nationalities = [
    Nationality(id: 3, name: "Indian"),
    Nationality(id: 4, name: "Philippines")
]

let randomNationalityIds = [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4]
let nationalitiesResult = Set(randomNationalityIds).flatMap { id in
    nationalities.filter({ id == $0.id }).first
}

print(nationalitiesResult)
```

> **Output**: [__lldb_expr_136.Nationality(id: 4, name: "Philippines"), __lldb_expr_136.Nationality(id: 3, name: "Indian")]

You don't need to keep these in order because the id and name are in the same place.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a non-unique array first and reducing it to a unique array afterwards you could as well collect the nationality strings in a `Set` of Nationalities:

```
var nationalitySet = Set<String>()
...
for nationality in decodedNationalities {
    nationalitySet.append(nationality)
}
```

A set won’t store any duplicates so if you add a nationality which is already contained it won’t be added again.

As the set is unordered but converting it into a sorted array is an easy one:

```
let nationalities = nationalitiesSet.sorted { $0.name < $1.name }
```

This solution does, however, require `Nationality` to be hashable, i. e. it must conform to the `Hashable` protocol:

```
struct Nationality: Hashable {
    var name: String
    var id: Int
}
```